# Fortran 2003 - array operation - is there a faster/better way to do this that doesn't involve a DO loop?

Tags: arrays, fortran, fortran2003

I have a problem which involves using a small rank 2 array (array2 in code below) to hold an ordered list of some of the elements of a much larger rank 4 array (array1 below). At the moment, one of my steps involves the use of a DO-loop, and I'm wondering whether it is possible to do this in one step using some sort of 'array-to-array' operation? In the main code I'm writing, I've found that using such 'array-to-array' operations wherever possible has led to significant speed increases. I've got the feeling that this is a simple problem, but I cannot see a solution or find one online. I'd gratefully appreciate any help! The following code is a simplified model of the problem, but contains the essential feature. Thanks.

```
PROGRAM vec_array

IMPLICIT none

INTEGER :: i,j,k,l,cnt
INTEGER :: array1(-1:1, -2:2, -2:2, 3:6)
INTEGER :: array2(5,4)

! Set up arbitrary array of values in 'large' array
cnt=0
DO i=-1,1,1
  DO j=-2,2,1
    DO k=-2,2,1
      DO l=3,6,1

        cnt=cnt+2*l
        array1(i,j,k,l)=cnt

      END DO
    END DO
  END DO
END DO

! array2 holds an ordered list of array1 elements 
array2(1,:)=[-1, 2,-2, 6]
array2(2,:)=[ 0, 1, 2, 3]
array2(3,:)=[-1,-2,-2, 4]
array2(4,:)=[ 1, 2, 2, 5]
array2(5,:)=[-1,-2,-2, 3]

! This is the key step here - is there another way to do this, 
! potentially faster, that does not involve a DO-loop?
DO i=1,5,1
  array1( array2(i,1),array2(i,2),array2(i,3),array2(i,4) )=i
END DO

DO i=-1,1,1
  DO j=-2,2,1
    DO k=-2,2,1
      DO l=3,6,1

        WRITE(*,*) i,j,k,l,array1(i,j,k,l)

      END DO
    END DO
  END DO
END DO

END PROGRAM
```

Comment: Just FYI, your program is not `Fortran 90`, you are using `Fortran 2003` features.

Comment: Otherwise I don't believe there is such a solution. Even vector subscript is not usable here. More importantly, I don't see any reason why such a solution would be faster. Modern tricks shorten code, but usually don't speed up the code.

Comment: Note also that your `increment` argument of `1` is superfluous, Fortran does step sizes of 1 implicitly.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers guys, I feared it might be so, but it's helpful to know that this procedure's essentially as fast as can be... Thanks too for pointing out that it's 2003 I'm using!

Comment: Efficient loop ordering may still improve speed for you. Have you had a critical look at memory access patterns?

Answer (score 0):

One point: I assume your real problem is a lot bigger? These tiny arrays would fit in the smallest circles of the cache, and I don't think that you'll be able to get much more performance through fancy code rewriting. And if it is bigger, you really need to profile the code to find the bottlenecks before spending too much time on rewriting code for speed.

One thing to note, perhaps also a bit off-topic, is that you are nesting your loops in C order (where the data close to each other in memory differ only in the last index). But Fortran organizes its arrays in the opposite way, where the data close to each other in memory differ only in the first index. The way you have currently organized `array1` is in the worst possible way, where the innermost loop involves the biggest strides in memory. It is good to get into the habit of arranging your data and nesting your loops to access contiguous memory as much as possible.